# I want to create custom toggle switch with animation color - swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

How can I create a switch in SwiftUI with custom design?

I attached example of the look that I want to achieve.

[image]

Comment: You have to create one yourself. This instant he place to ask for free code so give t a try and if you have trouble implementing som e part of it we can help you. take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. The [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui)  are a good start.

Answer (score 5):

Using a custom view container:

```
 struct ToggleView<Content: View>: View {
    @Binding var isOn: Bool
    var backGround: Content
    var toggleButton: Content?
    init(isOn: Binding<Bool>, @ViewBuilder backGround: @escaping () -> Content, @ViewBuilder button: @escaping () -> Content? = {nil}) {
        self._isOn = isOn
        self.backGround = backGround()
        self.toggleButton = button()
    }
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { reader in
            HStack {
                if isOn {
                    Spacer()
                }
                VStack {
                    if let toggleButton = toggleButton {
                        toggleButton
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                    }else {
                        Circle()
                            .fill(Color.white)
                    }
                }.padding(2.5)
                .frame(width: reader.frame(in: .global).height)
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation {
                        isOn.toggle()
                    }
                }.modifier(Swipe { direction in
                    if direction == .swipeLeft {
                        withAnimation() {
                            isOn = true
                        }
                    }else if direction == .swipeRight {
                        withAnimation() {
                            isOn = false
                        }
                    }
                })
                if !isOn {
                    Spacer()
                }
            }.background(backGround)
            .clipShape(Capsule())
            .frame(width: 60, height: 30)//control the frame or remove it and add it to ToggleView
        }
    }
}

struct Swipe: ViewModifier {
    @GestureState private var dragDirection: Direction = .none
    @State private var lastDragPosition: DragGesture.Value?
    @State var position = Direction.none
    var action: (Direction) -> Void
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .gesture(DragGesture().onChanged { value in
                lastDragPosition = value
            }.onEnded { value in
                if lastDragPosition != nil {
                    if (lastDragPosition?.location.x)! < value.location.x {
                        withAnimation() {
                            action(.swipeRight)
                        }
                    }else if (lastDragPosition?.location.x)! > value.location.x {
                        withAnimation() {
                            action(.swipeLeft)
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
    }
}

enum Direction {
    case none
    case swipeLeft
    case swipeRight
    case swipeUp
    case swipeDown
}
```

Usage:

With Custom Button:

```
ToggleView(isOn: $isOn) {
    Color.blue //you can use anything Image, Color, View.... & you can use different images depending on the toggle state using an if statement
}button: {
    Color.green //you can use anything Image, Color, View.... & you can use different images depending on the toggle state using an if statement
}.frame(width: 60, height: 30)
```

Without Custom Button:

```
ToggleView(isOn: $isOn) {
    Color.blue //you can use anything Image, Color, View.... & you can use different images depending on the toggle state using an if statement
}.frame(width: 60, height: 30)
```

[image]