# How to do shadow inside UISwitch in UIKit?

Tags: swift, uikit

The current UISwitch looks like this.

[image: 1]

I want to do UISwitch looks like this.

[image: 2]

How can I add shadow inside `UISwitch`?

Comment: you have to create a custom switch, there is an example in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70744653/i-want-to-create-custom-toggle-switch-with-animation-color-swiftui

Answer (score 0):

That's not what a UISwitch looks like, so you would need to build your own custom UIControl.